# Too many > in sublimerepl R output

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I know I've seen this mentioned somewhere, but i cannot for the life of me find it again. I use sublimerepl and R on Windows 10 and when I eval the following code:

```
x = (1:10)
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
print(mean(x))
```

I get the following output:

```
> x = (1:10)
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
print(mean(x))
> > > > [1] 5.5
>
```

As you can see, there are too many >, exactly one per line to be exact. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So the post is about sprintf, and nothing to do with read.csv, unlist? I would simplify it to: `sprintf("Mean: %s", mean(1:10))`

Comment: The post is about sublimeREPL only, sorry if the example made it confusing. I do need the extra lines though, but I'll make it more clear.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, ignore my comment, your post is good as it is now. Every `>` represent one command line.

Comment: Made it more general to avoid any confusion. I think you made a good point.

Comment: @Andreascmj so are you writing this code in another tab, then sending it to SublimeREPL to be evaluated? Can you describe the exact sequence of events?

Comment: Exactly, I write the code in a .r file and then press ctrl+,, f to eval it in the REPL. The output includes first the code that is getting evaluated and then  the results, but for some reason a lot of >'s gets printed as well.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to replicate the behavior on OS X and Linux using recent versions of R 3.2, but I didn't see anything abnormal - there was a `>` on each line of  text transferred with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>. I just booted into my Win7 virtual machine with R 3.2.3, and now I'm seeing what is described in the question:

[image]

It must be Windows-specific behavior, then. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with SublimeREPL's internals to suggest a cause or solution, and the package's author has essentially abandoned it, judging from the lack of participation in new issues on [Github](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), so I don't really have a solution, except to switch operating systems.

The altered display of transferred text doesn't affect its evaluation in any way, so while it doesn't exactly look pretty, it's harmless.